# mvn jetty:run throwing java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size

Tags: maven, maven-jetty-plugin

Im trying to run a pretty basic project (its basicly a wireframe with no functionality at all, just some maven dependencies) in jetty. 
To do so I'm using mvn jetty plugin:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

But im getting this exception just after the server begins to start-up:

```
[INFO] Starting jetty 7.4.0.v20110414 ...
2012-08-16 13:25:22.237:INFO::jetty-7.4.0.v20110414

java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 3313 but got 2163 bytes)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:386)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:156)
at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:195)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:100)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:78)
at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextEntry(JarInputStream.java:130)
at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextJarEntry(JarInputStream.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JarScanner.matched(JarScanner.java:153)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.PatternMatcher.matchPatterns(PatternMatcher.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.PatternMatcher.match(PatternMatcher.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JarScanner.scan(JarScanner.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.preConfigure(MetaInfConfiguration.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:406)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:435)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:253)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:67)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:468)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:408)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:589)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

This sound to me like a corrupt jar somewhere, but I'm not sure how to proceed, this is my first time working with jetty.

Any ideas?

Comment: could be an issue with that particular jetty version. try deploying the war in a different web server (like tomcat). If it works there ,try a different version of jetty (even an earlier one)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue, as I suspected, was due a corrupt JAR file. The solution for me was to clear my local repository (deleteing the content of **.m2/repository** folder) and execute:

```
mvn clean install
```

After all dependencies are resolved, it ran like a charm.

You should also ensure that the application is in fact being compiled to the output folder (in my case a folder called ***war***) before jetty is started.

Comment: you should accept your own answer since the question is now solved

Comment: I will do once the required 48hrs have concluded =)

Answer (score 4):

I found the following: [How to programmatically copy jar files](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-programmatically-copy-jar-files.html)

This article said:

> It usually occurs when text file entries in the source jar file
>   contain some non-ASCII characters such as ^I ^Z ^D ^C. Some common
>   files are META-INF/COPYRIGHT.html, META-INF/LICENSE.txt, etc, probably
>   because these files were created in a non-ASCII editor but saved as
>   text files. Open them in vi or vim to see these offending characters.

Maybe this is the cause of the error.